# Randomly failing spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

In my Rails tests I have this one failing randomly:

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe Api::V2::ClientsController, type: :controller do
  context 'happy path' do

    let!(:clients) {
      [create(:client), create(:client)]
    }

    it 'return authorized user resource in JSON format' do
      get :codes, format: :json

      expect(response).to be_success

      expect(json_response['clients'].size).to eql(2)

      expect(json_response['clients'][0]).to eql('code' => clients[0].code)
      expect(json_response['clients'][1]).to eql('code' => clients[1].code)
    end
  end
end
```

[image]

I'm not sure about using this:

```
let!(:clients) {
  [create(:client), create(:client)]
}
```

Comment: "randomly"?  How intermittently (frequency) does it fail?  This wil give you and us insight into the potential problem.

Comment: It fails only once in last 30 days.

Comment: What version of ruby, and rails, are you using?

Comment: I'm using 2.2.2 Ruby version.

Comment: Don't forget to select an answer if you find any of them helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that your controller fetches the records in no specific order (e.g. `Client.all`) and that your database doesn't guarantee any default order, either.

In that case, you can use [`contains_exactly`](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/contain-exactly-matcher):

```
expect(json_response['clients'].size).to eql(2)

expect(json_response['clients']).to contain_exactly(
  { 'code' => clients[0].code },
  { 'code' => clients[1].code }
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try swapping out the index numbers (json_response['clients'][0]) for something which doesn't rely on the json returned being in the right order.

For instance:

```
clients.each do |client|
  expect(json_response['clients'].collect{|x|x['code']}).to include(client.code)
end
```

If this fixes the problem, you may want to order the client records being returned from your controller.

Comment: this is overcomplicated, if you don't care about the order you can check that
`expect(json_response['clients'].map {|x| x[:code]}).to match_array(clients.map(&:code))`
or `=~` if you are on an old rspec.

Which will fail with a more helpful message

Comment: There's basically no difference between map and collect. match_array will work, but looks less like all the other ruby code you write. It's a question of preference. I wouldn't say either approach is over-complicated.